# Refresh Datatable through AJAX call Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, laravel-5.3

i'm using **Laravel Datatables 6.0** and jQuery, i want to do something which should be pretty simple, i have a list of signs for different people.

[image]

Like that and what i want, is to simply be able to *(when i click one of those columns)* filter the result set so that the only results returned are the ones where the Sign matches the one that was clicked.

So if you click "Tauro" you only get "Tauros", so on... how can this be achieved in jQuery Datatables using the Laravel Datatables package for Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to kinda figure it out, my solution ended being as follows:

```
        $(document).on('click', '.user-sign', function(e) {
            var sign = $(e.target).text();

            var table = $(".dataTable").DataTable();

            table.column( 6 )
                .search( sign )
                .draw();
        });
```

So i click the `.user-sign` and get the Text which indicates which Sign i want to query by. I get a reference to the **DataTable** *(note the Capital D)* and i tell it to query **column 6** *(where my signs are in the raw HTTP request)* and search by the Sign name i've retrieved. Then finally i tell it to redraw the table....

Not pretty but far less code than any other solution i've seen so far on the Internet. Hope this helps someone, if you guys have something to add or reasons why this should not be done go ahead and let me know. Thanks.